# PyQt5 context menu for QTableWidget column head

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget, qmenu

is there a way to get a context menu on a tables column head.

Find nothing about that in PyQt5's tuts.

the table's context menu is simple but the column heads don't affect.

```
# dlg is a QDialog object
self.tbl = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(dlg)
self.tbl.setContextMenuPolicy( Qt.CustomContextMenu )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `QHeaderView` of the `QTableWidget`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tbl = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10, self)

        for w in (self.tbl.horizontalHeader(), self.tbl.verticalHeader(), self.tbl):
            w.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
            w.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_customContextMenuRequested)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tbl)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customContextMenuRequested(self, pos):
        widget = self.sender()
        if isinstance(widget, QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
            widget = widget.viewport()
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Foo Action")
        menu.exec_(widget.mapToGlobal(pos))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dialog()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Update:**

```
class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.tbl = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(10, 10, self)

        self.tbl.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tbl.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_customContextMenuRequested_tw)

        self.tbl.verticalHeader().setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tbl.verticalHeader().customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_customContextMenuRequested_vh)

        self.tbl.horizontalHeader().setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tbl.horizontalHeader().customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_customContextMenuRequested_hh)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.tbl)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customContextMenuRequested_tw(self, pos):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Foo Action TW")
        menu.exec_(self.tbl.viewport().mapToGlobal(pos))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customContextMenuRequested_vh(self, pos):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Foo Action VH")
        menu.exec_(self.tbl.verticalHeader().mapToGlobal(pos))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customContextMenuRequested_hh(self, pos):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        menu.addAction("Foo Action HH")
        menu.exec_(self.tbl.horizontalHeader().mapToGlobal(pos))
```

Comment: yes thanks! But it looks problematic if i want to show different menus for the column header and the table body - or i am wrong? But it could be done - probably - by another to another slot - i think

Comment: @jgsedi What you think is correct, I have added an example

Comment: yes that's exactly what i mean! one slot for each element! many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the context menu policy on the header itself (if I've understood correctly), so...

```
self.tbl = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(dlg)
self.tbl.horizontalHeader().setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
```

and connect to the [`QHeaderView::customContextMenuRequested](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#customContextMenuRequested) signal...

```
self.tbl.horizontalHeader().customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.handle_context_menu_request)
```